# Protect video from video from capturing

Tags: java, security, web, filesystems, system

I have a webpage with a video. I have to protect this video from capturing it from browser with video capturing programms. I think that for this task i need to check process list or something like this, but to do this i have to use Java. Could anyone give advice how to create this kind of programm. thanks!

Comment: 1) probably not java related. 2) I don't think you can totally prevent video capturing anyways.

Comment: Wrong type of question for this site.  Too broad.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the right type of questions we can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is not possible to prevent user from video capturing. You can make it harder but you will never prevent user from capture screen of his computer. Even if you will control process list of computer (which i guess impossible or impossible for most users) You still cant prevent video capture from computer's video output.

You asking about thing that looks like DRM. History shows that task unsolveable.

You can try identify capturing users (if they will drop your video to torrent). With special unique marks which you can add to video for user. google: steganography

Comment: i just have to detect when it starts and stop playing my video

Comment: Maybe it can be possible to detect some browser plugin for video capture. But how you will detect that user pc connected to video capture device instead of display... impossible

Comment: i just want to play my video in two threads: 1 - video stream, 2- watermark with user ID. And stop playing my video when user opens programm to capture screen.

Comment: Biggest media companies trying to solve this problem (DRM). But all valueble DRM was broken (often even without external video capture)

Comment: watermark with user id good idea. Dont forget, that user can remove it with video editor, so use steganograhy instead.

Comment: of course any programm can be hacked. but i have to make is harder to broke

Comment: but it is real problem to detect that users start capturing. Even if you installing your app to the user pc (web browser dont let you big privilegies at user pc)

Comment: http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/image-protection-on-the-web maybe intresting for you

Comment: that's the good idea to add invisible symbols which tell us user id.